# Ignore duplicates on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I have a table containing a shop_id, name and promotion_code. I want to get the amount of records for every shop_id, but there are some duplicate records where a promotion_code is used multiple times. I want to ignore these.

I have tried:

`SELECT shop_id, count(*) as total_entries FROM tbl GROUP BY shop_id`

This gives me the correct structure, but it does count all the duplicate rows. So I thought I'd try grouping them first on promotion_code, and then on shop_id:

`SELECT shop_id, count(*) as total_entries FROM tbl GROUP BY promotion_code, shop_id`

But this gives me all zero's as result.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Btw, it's impossible to return zeros for the posted Select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT shop_id, count(distinct promotion_code) as total_entries FROM tbl GROUP BY shop_id
```

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
select shop_id, count(distinct promotion_code)
from tbl
group by shop_id
```

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT shop_id, count(*) as total_entries FROM tbl GROUP BY promotion_code, shop_id

Instead of using (*) you could use DISTINCT function so that you will be sure that all data you try to group are all unique values.

You could do something like this:

`SELECT shop_id, COUNT(DISTINCT promotion_code) as total_entries FROM tbl GROUP BY shop_id`